# Kicad Eeschema window does not respond when opened in windows 10 (Not working)

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, schematics, kicad

I have just started with Kicad. Never used it before. I downloaded and installed kicad, opened it, created a new project. Everything is fine until that point. But when I open Eeschema window for schematic, the mouse cursor keeps on loading and the eeschema window never opens (not responding). I have tried the 32-bit stable version of the software as well but it did not solve my problem. I posted this problem on kicad forum as well but no one responded. I would really appreciate it if someone points me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine under Win 10 on my machine.  Try right-clicking the desktop icon and selecting "run as administrator" when you start it.

Comment: It doesn't work that way either.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask on Kicad support forums?

Comment: I did. But I have not got any response after waiting for many hours.

Comment: @JohnD can you please tell me which version of kicad do you have?

Comment: @ZeeshanDhillon I'm travelling so I'm not near my Kicad machine.  But it was recently downloaded so it would be the latest version.

Comment: All right. Thanks.

Comment: @ZeeshanDhillon - I see you asked your question [here on Kicad Info](https://forum.kicad.info/t/eeschema-window-not-responding/20648). Based on the error message that you gave there mentioning OpenGL, I *guess* the issue might be related to the display drivers for your specific graphics chip/card. But that is just a direction I would investigate, not an actual answer. FYI a few days ago, someone who had similar-sounding symptoms, posted their solution [here](https://forum.kicad.info/t/eeschema-not-responding-when-opening-schematicac/20621). Good luck.

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you for the info. I think OpenGL might not be the reason of this problem because when I open the schematic file directly from file explorer then it gives OpenGL error and does not respond. But when I tried to create a new schematic, it did not give OpenGL error. It just stopped responding. I will try the solution anyway. Thanks

Comment: I moved from version 5.1.5 to 5.0.1 and solved the problem. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: that isn't a solution. 7

Comment: It might be a bug. Not sure.

Comment: possibly..I am running 5.1.5 on windows10 and linux without any problems. this is graphics related. rename your local config directory (c:\user\%USERNAME%\AppData\....

Comment: Do you mean in environment variables?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this describes a software issue in a software that has open issue trackers.

Comment: OpenGL fix fixed the problem for me. Just download the openGl fix file, then paste the dll file on your program files if its 64 bit and prog*86 if its 32bit.It should work

Comment: Can you flesh this out - eg by providing a relevant link?

Comment: A few crucial details are missing. Vague hints as to what to do are not good enough with today's complicated OS's. This is 1/2 an answer at best.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an opengl issue. See https://forum.kicad.info/t/eeschema-not-responding-when-opening-schematicac/20621

(tldr you can switch kicad to software rendering within the config files. For details see linked forum post.)